# Word macro that removes highlight in batch from .doc documents (and saves it as .docx)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was searching for macro that batch opens .doc documents and save them as .docx. I have already found one. Now I want to remove any highlight (keep the text; as well as to do more cleaning operations) in all the documents. When I add a line into it (to the best place I could guess), then it runs continuously without stopping after the last document. Any idea where and how to do amend it ?

```
Sub batch_cleaner()

Dim strFilename As String
Dim strDocName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim fDialog As FileDialog
Dim intPos As Integer
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fDialog
    .Title = "Select folder and click OK"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    If .Show <> -1 Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled By User", , "List Folder Contents"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    strPath = fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1)
    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath + "\"
End With
If Documents.Count > 0 Then
    Documents.Close SaveChanges:=wdPromptToSaveChanges
End If
If Left(strPath, 1) = Chr(34) Then
    strPath = Mid(strPath, 2, Len(strPath) - 2)
End If
strFilename = Dir$(strPath & "*.doc")
While Len(strFilename) <> 0
    Set oDoc = Documents.Open(strPath & strFilename)
```

' here I was trying to add stuff

```
    strDocName = ActiveDocument.FullName
    intPos = InStrRev(strDocName, ".")
    strDocName = Left(strDocName, intPos - 1)
    strDocName = strDocName & ".docx"
    oDoc.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
    oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    strFilename = Dir$()
Wend

End Sub
```

And this code always ruins it:

```
 Selection.WholeStory
 Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the "short name" (8.3 name) for your `.docx` files.  It'll still have a name ending in `.doc` so it also finds your new file in the `dir$()` call.

This can be demonstrated at a command prompt fairly easily (fake `.doc` file just to show the name issue):

```
C:\> echo x> 1.docx
C:\> if exist *.doc echo y
y
C:\> dir *.doc
09/03/2014  06:27 PM                 3 1.docx
C:\> dir /x *.doc
09/03/2014  06:27 PM                 3 100FD~1.DOC  1.docx
```

So you see the short name, although hidden from normal view, is actually a `.DOC` file so it matches.  Likewise in your script it'll match.

A couple of options come to mind offhand:

- name the files to something else that won't match like `.xyz` and then do a bulk rename later
- use subdirectories to store the resulting files so it won't, again, match in the `dir$()` call

Comment: or enumerate all files into an array, then loop the array.

Comment: I dont think it is a problem with 8.3 names. Maybe only because I am doing something with the document, that`s why there is created hidden .doc document. Anyway, I need to have .docx at the end, so could you help me to amend my macro in a way, that it stores the result into a subfolder (which seems a good idea to me)?